# How to determine the largest and smallest of 3 integers

Tags: c

I'm doing work for college and I have to determine, which of the three input numbers is the largest, the smallest and one in the middle. But not with some values ​​(eg 2 5 4), and I really do not know what I'm going through something.

I think I am missing some condition in the else if.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    puts("Enter three numbers separated by a space to determine what is the greatest, what is the one in the middle and what is the lowest.\n");

    unsigned int a, b, c;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    char z[] = "The three numbers are equal.\n";
    char x1[] = "is greater than the two equal numbers you entered."; char x2[] = "Is less than the two equal numbers you entered.";
    char y1[] = "is the largest,"; char y2[] = "is in the middle"; char y3[] = "is the lowest.";

    if (a==b && b==c && c==a) printf("%s\n",z);
    else if (a>b && b==c) printf("%d %s (%d)\n",a,x1,b); else if (a<b && b==c) printf("%d %s (%d)\n",a,x2,b);
    else if (a>c && c==b) printf("%d %s (%d)\n",a,x1,c); else if (a<c && c==b) printf("%d %s (%d)\n",a,x2,c);
    else if (b>a && a==c) printf("%d %s (%d)\n",b,x1,a); else if (b<a && a==c) printf("%d %s (%d)\n",b,x2,a);
    else if (b>c && c==a) printf("%d %s (%d)\n",b,x1,c); else if (b<c && c==a) printf("%d %s (%d)\n",b,x2,c);
    else if (c>a && a==b) printf("%d %s (%d)\n",c,x1,a); else if (c<a && a==b) printf("%d %s (%d)\n",c,x2,a);
    else if (c>b && b==a) printf("%d %s (%d)\n",c,x1,b); else if (c<b && b==a) printf("%d %s (%d)\n",c,x2,b);

    else if (a>b>c) printf("%d %s %d %s %d %s\n",a,y1,b,y2,c,y3);
    else if (a<b<c) printf("%d %s %d %s %d %s\n",c,y1,b,y2,a,y3);
    else if (b>a>c) printf("%d %s %d %s %d %s\n",b,y1,a,y2,c,y3);
    else if (b<a<c) printf("%d %s %d %s %d %s\n",c,y1,a,y2,b,y3);
    else if (c>a>b) printf("%d %s %d %s %d %s\n",c,y1,a,y1,b,y3);
    else if (c>b>a) printf("%d %s %d %s %d %s\n",c,y1,b,y2,c,y3);
    else if (a<b>c && c<a) printf("%d %s %d %s %d %s\n",b,y1,a,y2,c,y3); // b a c
    else if (a<b>c && a<c && c<b) printf("%d %s %d %s %d %s\n",b,y1,c,y2,a,y3); // b c a
    else if (a<c>b && b<a) printf("%d %s %d %s %d %s\n",c,y1,a,y2,b,y3); // c a b
    else if (a<c>b && a<b) printf("%d %s %d %s %d %s\n",c,y1,b,y2,a,y3); // c b a
    else if (b<a>c && c<b) printf("%d %s %d %s %d %s\n",a,y1,b,y2,c,y3); // a b c
    else if (b<a>c && b<c) printf("%d %s %d %s %d %s\n",a,y1,c,y2,b,y3); // a c b



    else {
        printf("There's no valid data");}
}
```

I also wanted to ask suggestions to optimize the code. The idea is that it is as optimized as possible.

Comment: You don't miss an `if`, you missed to reduce your `if`s.

Comment: Oh my.  That's some elaborate code.

Comment: You should consider using a loop.

Comment: This probably doesn't do what you think it does: `a>b>c`. It will be treated something like `(a>b)>c`, where `a>b` will evaluate to 1 or 0. So the check becomes either `1>c` or `0>c`, not anything to do with `a` or `b`. If that doesn't help you out, please post a shorter example of the problem you're having, that code snippet is quite large!

Comment: I'm using gcc to compile, and i.e when I enter "2 5 4" the output return "4 is the largest, 5 is in the middle and 2 is the lowest".. Not logic. That's my problem.

Comment: I used to set this as an exercise when I taught CS (30 years ago). The idea was folks would figure out that 'sorting' the three numbers into a known order (e.g. ascending) makes everything much easier. See how many unique cases there are when the numbers are in a known order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing that's wrong with your code is that C++ can't do things like `a < b < c`. That means `(a < b) < c`, which will be either `1 < c` or `0 < c`. You have to do `a < b && b < c`.

Also, you are doing a little too much work there. I don't think I've ever seen so many `else if`s.

You can define two functions that will return the bigger and smaller of two numbers:

```
int imax(int a, int b) {
    return a < b ? b : a;
}

int imin(int a, int b) {
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
```

then use it on all three to get the high, middle and lowest numbers.

```
int high = imax(imax(a, b), c);
int mid  = imax(imin(imax(a, b), c), imin(a, imax(b, c)));
int low  = imin(imin(a, b), c);
```

Then do two checks, one if they are all equal, and one if two are equal. If neither of those two checks are true, then they are all unequal and you can give the low, hi, and medium numbers, like this:

```
if (high == mid && mid == low)
    // all numbers are the same
else if (high == mid || high == low || mid == low)
    // two of the numbers are the same
else
    // the numbers are not the same, output high, mid, and low
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying your way and seems to be incredible more effective!

Comment: mid == low in the else if are not working fine for me. If I put this in the code, all  of the outputs will use his printf... Any idea of why?

Comment: @user1178392 sorry, I can't imagine what code you are trying based on your description. Please update your question with the code you are using now so I can see it.

Comment: Was a problem In my end, sorry for that. I wanna ask you one last thing: how can I limit the results only for numbers? I'm using a scanf and if I write text instead numbers in the input, the code returns random results. Any idea of how to avoid that?

Comment: @user1178392 `scanf` returns the number of items that were successfully read, so just compare the return value of `scanf` with 1 to make sure it read the number, and if it's not 1, then quit the program or try to read it again (in a loop) or whatever.

Comment: Can you help with this? (Sorry, I'm new in C).

Comment: @user1178392 you should accept an answer to this question by clicking the check mark beside the answer that answered your question, and then ask another question about that. It's too much to do in a comment.

Comment: There's a problem with the int mid, because It don't return me the real mid value... What should arrange for it to work?

Answer (score 7):

```
if (a>b>c)
```

This does not do what you think it does.  C does not support "chained conditionals" (few common languages do).  You need to check `a > b && b > c` explicitly.  Otherwise you are comparing a vs. b, and if that produces a "true" result, which is 1 in C, you will compare 1 vs. c, else 0 vs. c.  That's not what you intended, surely.

Edit: as for optimization, forget that.  Focus on making your program clear and concise first.  So you know, no normal program should have such a terrific wall of if/else clauses like yours does now.  I'd work on that first, because that is what sticks out like a sore thumb.

Answer (score 2):

You can write much simpler code using nested ifs.  I suggest starting:

```
if (a > b) {
   if (b > c) { 
     ...
```

Also, do you know if any of the numbers can be equal to each other?  That makes a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

One optimization suggestion would be to sort the numbers before deciding what to output. Then you only have four cases to deal with (all equal, one bigger, one smaller, all inequal).

Also, I believe that in C if you write `a < b < c`, it first evaluates `a < b` to either 0 or 1, and then evaluates `1 < c` or `0 < c`.

Answer (score 1):

If you determine which is the biggest, then what would you know about the other 2? Divide and conquer.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question in a different way, here is how you might find the minimum and maximum numbers in a data file on the shell:

```
$ echo 2 12 8 > data.txt
$ cat data.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -n | head -n 1
2
$ cat data.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -n | tail -n 1
12
```

First `cat` concatenates the contents of the files listed, here just `data.txt` (eg, it reads the file). Next, `tr`, translates space characters, `' '`, into newlines, `'\n'`. Then, `sort` sorts each line numerically `-n`. Finally, `head` prints a number of lines, here 1, from the start (eg, the lowest number) and `tail` prints a number of lines, again just 1, from the end (eg, the highest number).

Comment: I don't think it answers the question, it is c homework - why would he want to use bash? :\

Comment: I did take his first line, "I have to determine which of the three input numbers is the largest," somewhat over literally. It is still useful to consider what a high level solution looks like before implementing in C. Saying as three numbers is likely to turn into four numbers in short order, a good C solution aught to follow the same structure as the pipeline above, with distinct load, transform, and extract steps.

Answer (score -1):

Since what you need is the smallest and the largest of three numbers, you can create two functions, one that returns the smallest value and one that returns the largest value; then you print the results.

Note:  It is a good idea to compartmentalize your code.  Have small functions to do one little task at a time. You will find that it is easier to create code in this way and other people will appreciate that when they have to read your program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int smallestVal(int val1, int val2, int val3);
int largestVal(int val1, int val2, int val3);

int main()
{
 //Assuming these are your numbers:
 int first=7;
 int second=4;
 int third=5;

 int smallest=0;  //These are what you aiming for
 int largest=0;

 smallest = smallestVal(first, second, third);
 largest = largestVal(first, second, third);

 printf("smallest=%d  largest=%d\n", smallest, largest);
 return 0;
}

int smallestVal(int val1, int val2, int val3)
{
 int smallest = val1;

 if (val2 <= smallest)
 smallest = val2;

 if(val3 <= smallest)
 smallest = val3;

 //continue adding more if... you need so.
 //but remember to add more arguments to your function.

 return smallest;
}

int largestVal(int val1, int val2, int val3)
{
    int largest = val1;

    if(val2 >=largest)
    largest = val2;

    if(val3 >= largest)
    largest = val3;

    //continue adding more if... you need so.
    //but remember to add more arguments to your function.

    return largest;
}
```

Comment: Good advice, but you generally should just give hints, not full solutions, to homework problems.

Comment: When people are new into programming a good example, with clear steps, teach them better than 1000 hints. They can see the style of the program; they can see where things fit more clearly.

Comment: I know you're trying to be helpful, but I consider giving someone the answer to a homework problem to be abetting cheating, although I realize not everyone feels as strongly about this.  FWIW, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions